# Как дать временные права пользователю для обновления программы?

Tags: powershell

Ситуация: 
У пользователя не хватает прав для обновления программы.
Нужен скрипт для временного права доступа к обновлению программы, который он может запустить сам, а затем после обновления эти права отобрать как до обновления
Возможно ли это? Если да, то как реализовать?

Comment: А вульгарного `RunAs /user:updater` co сложным паролем, вводимым программно и воссоздаваемым в рантайме - недостаточно? Зачем правами играть, если можно для такой процедуры создать отдельного пользователя, которому к тому же запрещено логиниться локально или получать доступ из сети удалённо...

Comment: вшивать пароли в батник небезопасно, а так же при смене пароля придется переписывать пароль в батнике